# How to make bootable command prompt in USB ? (cmd.iso)

Tags: boot, batch-file, cmd.exe, iso-image

I like to run command prompt or batch file in usb pendrive like Bootable os.

I had a file `file.bat` , which contains,

```
net user %username% reset password
```

i want to run without getting into windows OS.
Mean, from my guess it can be possible only while before booting OS. So, like windows installation iso, i hope cmd.iso too possible.

If yes, please help me guys. I hope you understood my Question.

Note : Googling with this topic only i can able to find bootable USB via cmd. But, pls note, I don't need how to boot usb via cmd. I need cmd in bootable USB.

I want to run `file.bat` as OS.

Comment: Where should the content of `%username%` come from? No login, no username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want access to a command prompt before the login screen of Windows. It also seems like you want to run a batch script with it to reset the login credentials of a profile. Even if I am wrong about the latter you will be satisfied enough with the former.

First and foremost, it is not possible to run a batch script outside of Windows, outside of CMD; the best you can do is before login during startup.

Let's create 2 batch scripts for our purposes (since you seem consistent on batch scripts today, you can also run these individually by line if you wish). If you have access to a Windows Administrator account you should create part1a.bat; if not, you need to create part1b.bat. You will create part2.bat in both cases.

**part1a.bat - Use this if you can log in to an admin profile**

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup /v SetupType /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup /v CmdLine /t REG_SZ /d "cmd.exe" /f
exit
```

**part1b.bat - Use this if you cannot**

```
REM Replace drive F: with whatever drive the main OS is on
reg load HKLM\TempHive213 F:\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM
reg add HKLM\TempHive213\Setup /v SetupType /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
reg add HKLM\TempHive213\Setup /v CmdLine /t REG_SZ /d "cmd.exe" /f
exit
```

**part2.bat - (modify this to your liking, but keep top 2 lines)**

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup /v SetupType /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup /v CmdLine /t REG_SZ /d "" /f
REM Replace the user info below to what you want.
net user %username% %newpassword%
exit
```

1. If you have access to a live Windows administrator account then run `part1a.bat` with Admin privileges and skip to step 4; if you do not, proceed to step 2.
2. Boot to the Windows Installation ISO. Choose "Repair your PC" or "Repair your computer." Click "Command Prompt." Now you need to know the driver letters to do so you may use `diskpart`. Run `diskpart` and run `list vol`. Every drive should have been assigned a driver letter; if not, you can do so yourself by running these two consecutively: `select vol <num>` and `assign letter=<letter>`.
3. If you need to reassign the driver letter to the batch script do so by running `notepad D:\part1b.bat` (replace the letter respectively and to its location) then modifying it, then saving it. Then run `D:\part1b.bat`.
4. Restart the computer. Once restarted, during or after the Windows Boot Logo and before you ever get to the Windows Log In screen a CMD prompt with Admin privileges will appear. Use `diskpart` again to differ what drive is which and then run `D:\part2.bat`. If you haven't already please replace the line describing replacing the user credentials with the ones you want, by running `notepad D:\part2.bat`. If you did use the original part2.bat I specified it would set a password.

Note: `diskpart` may not tell you exactly which is which, you may have to try using the `cd /d F:` (replace letter) and `dir` in combination to figure out which drive is which.

Comment: Thx its worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a batch file like an OS, it just doesn't work like that. The batch interpreter is a part of Windows and if you boot your computer from a pendrive, you aren't in windows anymore and therefore, there is no way for your batch to be executed.

In order for a bootloader to actually load your software (i.e. boot it) you would need to write a boot sector for the bootloader.

You could then add a batch interpreter on top, but that is probably not what you want.

Comment: the batch interpreter is part of cmd.exe

Comment: which itself is a part if windows