# Boot Windows XP or 7 directly into an application WITHOUT DISPLAYING ANYTHING OF WINDOWS (such as progress bar, "Welcome" screen, mouse cursor etc)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, autorun

Basically what I want to do is for Windows to load and then boot directly into an application in fullscreen mode, but before the application launches I want absolutely nothing of Windows to show. So I want the Windows loading screen to just be blank, I don't want the "Welcome" screen to show, and the mouse cursor must never appear before the application has launched. So basically, turn the computer on and as soon as Windows starts to load, the screen must be entirely blank, all until the application within Windows launches in fullscreen.
Is this possible? Either in Windows XP or 7. I have looked everywhere it seems and while the Windows loading screen / progress bar appears to be possible to hide, I have not found a way to hide the Welcome screen. Well, I think I read the actual "Welcome" can be removed, but I would still get the blue Windows background and cursor visible for a few seconds before the application is launched.
Any suggestions or is it simply impossible? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Answer these questions, and I may have a method that might work: Does or can the program that you intend to run have the ability to "auto" fullscreen just from starting it? The method I have will show the Windows Logo (then if possible, would start the application fullscreen), is this acceptable? The mouse may not be used at any point from the point Windows starts to when the computer turns off, is this acceptable? What is the program that you intend to run? - it *likely* has to be a specific type of Windows application. Are you essentially trying to create a locked out system?

Comment: Thank you for answering! Yes, I have created a *.bat file which will boot the program into fullscreen. The mouse does not need to be used, ever. I'm sorry, but I don't know what a locked out system is. Do you mean if the computer will only be used to run this said program, and nothing else? If so, yes that is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Okay, within the hour I will have a response for you, however, the application you are using may not work because the Windows kernel may not be fully loaded up. For instance, if the program you plan to execute is very graphical based WIndows may not be able to run it because it does not have access to its more complex libraries.

Answer (score 1):

This will only work for Windows 7 as far as I know. Never tested it on Windows XP, you can try (just see if the same registry keys and values are there). "However, the application you are using may not work because the Windows kernel may not be fully loaded up. For instance, if the program you plan to execute is very graphical based WIndows may not be able to run it because it does not have access to its more complex libraries."

To make the mouse invisible you will need to disable the mouse via command line. For this, you should use [devcon.exe created by Microsoft](https://networchestration.wordpress.com/2016/07/11/how-to-obtain-device-console-utility-devcon-exe-without-downloading-and-installing-the-entire-windows-driver-kit-100-working-method/); unfortunately, you may have to follow that guide to obtain it. Once you have it add to your batch file `Drive:\Path\to\devcon.exe disable <hwid>` where <hwid> is the Hardware ID of your mouse (which can be found via properties in Device Manager or through one of the switches for `devcon.exe` which would give a name to it). Put this code before where it starts the program (the mouse while disabled, the pointer, on the other hand, *may* show - which you can follow @Ivan's suggestion and make the pointer invisible).

For the most part, I'm following [an older post of mine](https://superuser.com/questions/1244757/how-to-make-bootable-command-prompt-in-usb-cmd-iso/1244794#1244794) which uses the same method. If you ever want to undo what this will do (this post combined with this should help you undo using logic) by undoing what you are going to do now using a bootable Installation disk for windows.

1. Open `regedit` and head to `HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup` you may have to start it with Administrative Privileges (by being on the user account)
2. Adjust the REG_DWORD value `SetupType` to `2` (or `0` for reverting)
3. Adjust the REG_SZ value `CmdLine` to `Drive:\the\path\to\your\batch.bat` (or null (which means blank) for reverting)
4. Restart, have fun! If it doesn't work properly such the application will not load, you should have a Windows Installation Disk or Drive ready, so you can easily fix your problems by booting to it.

Comment: Thank you! I will install Windows 7 and give it a try. Do you happen to also know if there is any way to set Windows 7 up so that it automatically powers off when I exit the program I will autorun on boot?

Comment: @krs000, You need to make the batch file wait until the program exits. After that line, you should do "shutdown -s -f -t 0"

Comment: Do you know how do I make the batch file wait until the program exits? What line would I need to add. If you know, would you mind sharing? Because I have no clue. :-(

Comment: @krs000 Instead of running `start C:\myprogram.exe`, you should run it like `C:\myprogram.exe` as a single line in a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the background to an image of your application and probably set a custom (invisible) cursor, if that is the only concern.

It might be possible to set the video output to another (possibly nonexistent) monitor, and then switch it when the program starts up, but I suspect a hight probability of glitches.

You could also try running your program under wine or virtualbox, under linux, which is much more customizable, but it may be complicated.

If you can add hardware, possibly easier and more full-proof would be to add a relay, cutting power or data to your monitor, that your program would activate. E.g. KVM (or just M) switches are not that expensive and maybe you could somehow rig it up from your program.

Comment: Unfortunately, most of what you're suggesting is way beyond my limited knowledge. :-(
I was thinking of making the mouse pointer invisible, but what would happen when I exit the program, to turn the computer off, and there is no cursor? Is it possible to set Windows up so that the computer automatically powers off when I exit the program?

Comment: The cursor would be there, you just wouldn't see it :D so anything complicated would require guess work, but many things can be done via keyboard, if you have one. Shut down is Ctrl+F4.